# formulatext filter in search - SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to add formulatext filter with DECODE function in a search in 2.0 Scheduled script.

```
search.createFilter({
        name: "formulatext:DECODE({custbody_sfdc_comm_id},"+groups+",0)",
        join: null,
        operator: search.Operator.IS,
        values: "1"
 })
```

groups is an array which is passed to search custbody_sfdc_comm_id field values in that array.
But when executed, it is throwing invalid search criteria

Answer (score 0):

When using a formula in the `search.createFilter()` constructor, you should specify the formula in the `formula` parameter rather than as part of the `name`:

```
search.createFilter({
    name: "formulatext",
    formula: "DECODE({custbody_sfdc_comm_id},"+groups+",0)",
    join: null,
    operator: search.Operator.IS,
    values: "1"
})
```